# Icon resizing to fit div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a div that can contain between 0 to 7 icons, depending on some selection. The icons are [ionicons](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#icons). Currently, my code is:

```
<div class="item item-text-wrap" style="text-align:center;">
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #3b5998" ng-if="website" ng-click="openSocialLink('website')"><i class="icon ion-ios-world-outline" style="color:white"></i></button>
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #3b5998" ng-if="social.facebook" ng-click="openSocialLink('fb')"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook" style="color:white"></i></button>
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #007bb6" ng-if="social.linkedin" ng-click="openSocialLink('linkedin')"><i class="icon ion-social-linkedin" style="color:white"></i></button>
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #00aced" ng-if="social.twitter" ng-click="openSocialLink('twitter')"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter" style="color:white"></i></button>
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #bb0000" ng-if="social.youtube" ng-click="openSocialLink('youtube')"><i class="icon ion-social-youtube" style="color:white"></i></button>
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #eeee00" ng-if="social.snapchat" ng-click="openSocialLink('snapchat')"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat" style="color:white"></i></button>
    <button class="button" style="background-color: #c42da5" ng-if="social.instagram" ng-click="openSocialLink('instagram')"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram" style="color:white"></i></button>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make it so that the icons resize to take up one line exactly? The issue right now is that if their screen size is too small then this takes up multiple lines.

EDIT: Also, I've started using the [ionic grid system](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-even), now the issue is just that on smaller screen sizes theres no spacing between the items, is it possible to break into two lines if the space between them will be too small?

Comment: looks ok here == https://jsfiddle.net/opd1vf86/

Comment: You're right. Maybe another css change of ours is messing this up. Thanks!

Comment: Then Inspect the icons and see if any css from ionicons is crossed out or any other issues --  right click on an icon and choose inspect (chrome browser) -- inspect element (firefox) to see the CSS

Comment: Doing that now, thanks for the tip. Do you know if it's possible to do some sort of loner control? i.e. if one icon is pushed down, take two icons down instead of just one?

Comment: you can do that with Jquery or javascript -- click on the first icon and the tweeter icon activates too -- https://jsfiddle.net/r27p49z7/

Comment: Sorry, I guess i didn't explain that very well, I mean in a situation when the screen width is going to push one icon into a new line, you force it to push two down, so that it looks a bit more natural, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can easily be solved if you put a table.

This is the code.

```
<table style="text-align: center; margin: auto;"> <!-- to make the buttons in the center-->
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #3b5998" ng-if="website" ng-click="openSocialLink('website')"><i class="icon ion-ios-world-outline" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #3b5998" ng-if="social.facebook" ng-click="openSocialLink('fb')"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #007bb6" ng-if="social.linkedin" ng-click="openSocialLink('linkedin')"><i class="icon ion-social-linkedin" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #00aced" ng-if="social.twitter" ng-click="openSocialLink('twitter')"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #bb0000" ng-if="social.youtube" ng-click="openSocialLink('youtube')"><i class="icon ion-social-youtube" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #eeee00" ng-if="social.snapchat" ng-click="openSocialLink('snapchat')"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
            <td><button class="button" style="background-color: #c42da5" ng-if="social.instagram" ng-click="openSocialLink('instagram')"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram" style="color:white"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```